# Replace a String in a MySQL table using JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

```
UPDATE table
SET field = REPLACE(your_field, 'original_string', 'replace_string')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%original_string%'
```

Is there a way I could execute above query with JOOQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it translates pretty much 1:1. Just write it out like this:

```java
using(configuration)
  .update(TABLE)
  .set(TABLE.FIELD, 
       replace(TABLE.YOUR_FIELD, "original_string", "replace_string"))
  .where(TABLE.YOUR_FIELD.like("%original_string%"))
  .execute();
```

The [`DSL.replace()` method is documented in the Javadoc](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#replace-org.jooq.Field-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

#### The following static imports are assumed:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static com.example.your.schema.Tables.*;
```